# empty dataset after joined model scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

2 models with name scope:

class A 
scope :active, where("active = ?", true)
end

class B 
scope :active, where("active = ?", true)
end

In my console:

A.active and B.active individual i get the correct records. So this works fine.

Now i want to join the 2 scopes in one query with the & sign, like this:

A.active & B.active

The result is no error but the dataset is empty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is - & is Array intersection, and as A.active contains only As and B.active only Bs, the intersection will always be empty. Maybe you just want concatenation?
see
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-26
and
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-2B